# Android Emulator Screen Scale too Large

Tags: android-emulator

I've stumbled across a problem with my emulator and I've (tried) to googled the issue but I only come up with solutions for the actual emulator being too big, not for the issue I'm having.

It is a bit difficult to describe but it looks like running a 800*600 resolution on a very big screen without the graphics pixelating.

Due to the difficulty in explaining what it looks like I've linked (not allowed to attach just yet) a screenshot of the emulator, note the segment simulating the phone screen . It doesn't quite look as expected.

http://blog.nordenfelt.com/emulator.png

Has anyone come across this?
I'm running the latest versions of everything, made sure to upgrade before posting :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have the same problem what i did is go into Eclipse go to Windows => ADV Manager and Select the Emulator name 2.1-MAP and Select Edit on the screen go to the bottom and do you see Hardware to the right you see a LCD Density change that i changed mine to 120 or you can change it accordingly and select edit close it and restart your emulator. and that makes the screen resolution smaller.
I hope that helps

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this issue for a while but I'll give that a try when it happens again.