# Android AVD Screen Too Large

Tags: android

THe AVD setting for Android 2.2 seems too large on my computer, and this is the default value. How can I create one of normal size.  Thanks

I'm not the only one: [Android Emulator Screen Scale too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326866/android-emulator-screen-scale-too-large)

Comment: Adjust your screen resolution, by screen I mean your computer screen resolution and see if that helps :).

Comment: What value do you have the screen size set at? For me the default is WVGA800. If you use a custom resolution does it fix it?

Comment: +1, better guess than mine lol

Comment: Yes, it appears to be different size based on screen resolution.  I think the options for adjusting the emulator size on the target should be more clear too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-Click on your project, go to Run As-> Run Configurations, click on the tab 'Target', at the bottom you'll see 'additional emulator command line options', add '-scale 0.75' (to make the screen 75% of full size, set the value to what you want to scale)

Comment: yes this is correct.  A bit harder to find than one would expect given how common an issue this is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My emulator window was bigger than my computer screen resolution. I did what [DoNotCheckMyBlog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753603/donotcheckmyblog) said.

1. Choose a smaller screen resolution
2. Run emulator
3. Revert back to the original screen resolution size

The emulator will fit.